# Periodic Pattern recognition In a Sales Log

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I'm pretty new in this field and I need some advice for my first professional challenge.

I'm trying to create a sort of *client segmentation* from a my company's sales log which has the peculiarity that the clients has a pretty long-term relationship and a periodic behavior.

1. Based on when does he has bought (Ex: Twice a month, once a week, once every three months...) determine the ***frequency*** of purchase.
2. I need to figure out the ***phase*** of this client, so I can know in what stage of his/her period is.
3. I would like to know how much does it buys each time ***purchase amplitude***

Once i have his **three** elements I want to be able to use that info to detect when the client changes his behavior (specially when they have an missing period or they decrease the buying amplitude)

I would like to get a really neat result, because i think that i will use it to a Markovian process.

So far I've tried astropy's lomb-scargle implementation but it seems that is too-precise and needs to many data points.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. You seem to have ideas -- try them out! I'm sure there is no canonical best solution here, especially since we don't know what you data look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps you need to follow.

1. **Model**

   You need to pick a model that you think explains your data. It can be very simple (e.g. linear regression) or very complex (e.g. a four-layer neural network). You want to pick as simple a model as possible!

   *Example*: Assume sales follow $s(x) = a + b\sin(cx)$.
2. **Train**

   Using one part of the data, you determine which parameters of the model fit your data best. The method of training depends on your model of choice.

   *Example*: You fit the parameterized sine against the first half of your data with least-squares and find $(a,b,c) = (3,77, 13)$ is "best".
3. **Validate**

   Inspect how well the model explains the rest of the data. You will have to decide in step 1 how you quantify quality here, and what your acceptance criteria are.

   Separately, if that makes sense in your domain, apply the model entirely different data sets that *should* follow the same model if your hypotheses are correct. Does it predict anything there? What does the answer say about your model and/or your assumptions?

   *Example*: Inspecting the squared error between $3 + 77\sin(13x)$ and the second half of the timeline data, you notice it is far too large.
4. **Iterate**

   Unless the predictive quality of your model is good, go back to step 1. Sometimes, more training data can be the answer, too; note how that weakens your result, though.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, just a noob comment: Do you have any suggestions for  start building my model? (anything to read...)

Comment: @pedropedro That's unfortunately outside of my area of expertise, sorry. You'd have to look into ML and/or data science sources. [ai.SE], [datascience.SE] and [scicomp.SE] may be worth checking out, too.